# ¿Cómo usar Geonames.org para obtener a partir del código postal la colonia y el municipio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, kendoui

**Actualización**
Mi formulario esta en KendoUI, hice una solicitud ajax al sitio web geonames.org, en la consola me da el result que es un arreglo con toda la información que requiero, mi pregunta concisa es, como obtengo los datos de este array?, ya intente un par de formas pero parece que no reconoce lo que trato de llamar, ¿como saco los elementos de este array?, result.placeName y dice que no esta definido, me podrían ayudar?.

```
    $("#formuDireccion").kendoForm({
                formData: {
                    Calle: "",
                    NoExt: "",
                    NoInt: "",
                    Colonia: "",
                    Alcaldia: "",
                    CP: "",
                    Estado: "",
                    Ciudad: ""
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        type: "group",
                        layout: "grid",
                        grid: {cols: 3, gutter: 10},
                        items: [
                            {
                                field: "Calle",
                                label: "Calle:",
                                colSpan: 3,
                                validation: {required: true}
                            },
                            {
                                field: "NoExt",
                                label: "No. exterior"
                                , validation: {
                                    required: true,
                                    type: "number"
                                },
                                colSpan: 1
                            },
                            {
                                field: "NoInt",
                                label: "No. interior"
                                , validation: {
                                    required: true,
                                    type: "number"
                                }
                            },
                                {
                                field: "CP",
                                label: "CP:",
                                validation: {required: true,
                                    maxlength: "5",
                                    pattern: "[0-9]{5}",
                                    title: "CP INCORRECTO"},
                                colSpan: 1
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Colonia",
                                label: "Colonia:",
                                validation: {readonly: true},
                                colSpan: 1
                            },
                            {
                                field: "Alcaldia",
                                label: "Alcaldía: ",
                                colSpan: 1
                            }
                            ,
                            {
                                field: "Estado",
                                label: "Estado: ",
                                colSpan: 1
                            }
                            ,
                            {
                                field: "Ciudad",
                                label: "Ciudad: ",
                                colSpan: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ], buttonsTemplate: ""
            });
```

esta es la solicitud actualizada, solo que ahora no sé como obtener los valores e imprimirlos en #Colonia, #Alcaldia

```
                    $('#CP').on('change', function(){
                var cp = $(this);
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?",
                    cache: false,
                    datatype: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        postalcode: cp.val(),
                        country: "MX",
                        username: "username"
                    },
                    
                    success: function(result, success) {
                        console.log(result);
                        /*$("#Colonia").val(result.placeName);
                        $("#Alcaldia").val(result.adminName2);*/
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                        console.log(`Error ${error}`);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: ¿Qué fue lo que ya intentaste para hacer la petición?

Comment: Pues esto fue lo que intente

        const Url = 'api.geonames.org/postalCodeSearch?';
                $('#CP').on('change', function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: Url,
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function(result){
                            console.log(result);
                        },
                        error: function(error){
                            console.log(`Error ${error}`);
                        }
                    });
                });

Comment: Te sale algun error en la consola del navegador cuando se lanza esa petición?

Comment: no, ya me hace la petición, pero no me trae los datos que quiero jaja, me trae el documento completo de países con sus cps, entonces ahora no sé como solicitar digamos la region

Comment: En `geonames.org` se ve que podés filtrar por país. Al seleccionar cualquier país, en la URL aparece `&country=el_código_del_país`. [Probalo](https://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html).

Comment: ya lo implemente pero ahora me no manda mi solicitud de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré respuesta, al mandar la solicitud, te regresa un objeto y dentro del objeto hay un arreglo, lo único que hay que hacer es acceder jerárquicamente al valor que necesitas, para esto necesitarás el valor en consola, pongo la solución que me funciono.

```
            $('#CP').on('change', function(){
                var cp = $(this);
               
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?",
                    cache: false,
                    datatype: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: {
                        postalcode: cp.val(),
                        country: "MX",
                        username: "username"
                    },
                    
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#Colonia").val(data.postalcodes[0].placeName);
                        $('#Ciudad').val(data.postalcodes[0].adminName3);
                        $("#Alcaldia").val(data.postalcodes[0].adminName2);
                        $("#Estado").val(data.postalcodes[0].adminName1);
                   
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                        console.log(`Error ${error}`);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Genial. ¿Podrías [edit] tu respuesta y mostrar cómo hacés la petición? Para que otras personas con la misma pregunta puedan saberlo.

Comment: Listo, ya esta la respuesta completa :D